# npm run build is not including /public/images/images.png

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-boilerplate, imageloader

I am just testing the React Boilerplate with Material UI, and I am using some png images (stored in `/public/images/`). If I `npm start` the project load those images like a charm, but once I type in `npm run build` the builded project does not load the images in `/public/images/`. I am using React 16.8.6 and I am loading the images this way:

```
<Avatar src="../../public/images/my_image.png" ... />
```

After some research I tried importing images instead of loading it in the `src` prop of the component, but when `npm run build` still don't found any of them. Is there any configuration in the webpack I am missing or how can I solve this?

Comment: are you using create-react-app ?

Comment: If yes then transfer all your assets to public folder and then npm run build .

Comment: @SlimCoder, your suggestion doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I found was to install the `copy-webpack-plugin` and then modifying the webpack config like this:

```
plugins: options.plugins.concat([
   ...,
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'public' }])
])
```